# Not able leverage T-SQL to replace dollar sign with a blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm in the process of trying to remove a $ from cells in a specific column with nothing.  Basically, I want to take cells that resemble $3.45 and make the final product look like 3.45.

I've been working with the REPLACE command (with the backtick) and can't seem get it to work correctly.

Here's what I tried:

```
REPLACE('`$', '`$', '')
```

Do I need to throw a like command in there along with something to handle the blank space I want to replace the dollar signs with?  I know this may be a simple solution but I really want to learn this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance from @nickvaccaro and @vlad I ended up leveraging your suggestions with the following find and replace code:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET COLUMN_NAME = REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '$', '')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get rid of that back tick.  Check this out:

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(50)
SET @Value = '$3.50'

SELECT REPLACE(@Value, '$', '')
```

Answer (score 4):

you don't need the backtick. For example:

```
select replace('some$number','$','%') -- this returns "some%number"
```